# Issue combining L10N True w. I18N False in Django

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, locale, default

I have a extensive Django web service that is in use in 20+ countries.

The complete site is in english - but all code is 'trans' tagged so in future it will be possible to translate it - but for now I want all english language *but* use locale date/time/number formats.

I keep track of all users language and sets their locale to be used for L10N but have not made any translations at this stage.

In my settings file USE_I18N and USE_L10N are both True for now.

**Q: How can I keep trans-tagging all code (future proof) but not have Django I18N things (so everything is just in plain english) yet at the same time handle decimals, dates, time in L10N?**

I have attempted to change I18N to false but this also cause date formats to be non-L10N.

With current I18N and L10N True formats are ok, my trans are handled ok **but** I get all Django default translations being I18N so e.g. 'search' will be 'sök' to a swede but everything else is in english... :-(

/ Jens